# Como generar un report en un proyecto mvc 5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

Hola soy nuevo programando en asp.net mvc, pero queria saber o que me sugieran como generar un reporte para imprimir, la idea es que tengo he desarrollado una aplicación con una base de datos en sql server, a partir de la información crear el reporte y que el usuario pueda imprimirlo.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Indícanos qué tablas se emplearían para presentar el reporte, muéstranos algún formato a manera de bosquejo de cómo deseas ver tu reporte; es decir brinda más información específica sobre lo que deseas, tu pregunta da para "adivinar" lo que necesitas.

Comment: Hola, podrias usar Crystal Report para poder disenar facilmente tu reporte, luego para llenarlo con datos si necesitariamos mas informacion. Pero te recomiendo ese por ser gratis y de facil instalacion desde los paquetes Nuget de Visual Studio